# Get duplicate records with group rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql

[image]

Here is my table `StudyFieldOption`. I want to get all duplicate records whose count is greater than 1 based on `option` and `study_data_field_id`.
i.e. Two records are duplicate if they have same value in `option` and `study_data_field_id`.

I am trying the following but it is not working for me:

```
StudyFieldOption.select([:option, :study_data_field_id]).group(:study_data_field_id).having("count(*) > 1")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use multiple columns in `group`

```
StudyFieldOption.select(:option, :study_data_field_id)
                .group(:option, :study_data_field_id)
                .having("count(*) > 1")
```

Comment: What error you are getting ?? or what's wrong in it ?

Comment: LINE 1: ...tudy_data_field_id" HAVING count(*) > 1  ORDER BY "public"."...

Comment: on the quote sign before public

Comment: `StudyFieldOption.select(:option, :study_data_field_id).group(:option, :study_data_field_id).having("count(title) > 1").to_sql` what it returns ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
check = {}
dup_indices = []
StudyFieldOption.all.each do |field|
  unique_str = field.option + field.study_data_field_id.to_s
  if check.value?(unique_str)
    dup_indices << check.key(unique_str)
    dup_indices << field.id
  end
  check[field.id] = unique_str
end
puts dup_indices
```

Comment: Have a look at [`reduce`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce), [`each_with_object`](https://apidock.com/rails/Enumerable/each_with_object) and [`map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-map) - they'll help cut some of the superfluous code such as setting the `check` and `dup_indices` variables ahead of an `each` loop.

Comment: undefined method `str' for main:Object

Comment: Oh sorry str is python, I fixed it, it should work now